# Questions regarding inverse trigonometric integration

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

Intregrate $\displaystyle \int \frac{x+5}{\sqrt{9-(x-3)^2}} \, dx $

I split the integral

$$\int \frac{x+5}{\sqrt{9-(x-3)^2}} \, dx=\int \frac5{\sqrt{9-(x-3)^2}}\, dx+\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{9-(x-3)^2}} \, dx$$

For the first integral I use the integral table which states

$$ \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-u^2}} \, du  =  \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{u}{a}\right)  +C$$

where in this case:
$u=(x-3)$,
$a=3$
When you take out the constant of $5$, you would integate and the second integral would be

$$ =\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{9-(x-3)^2}} \, dx  +  5 \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{x-3}{3}\right) + C $$

I'm not sure how to integrate the first integral however...

Comment: Instead write $x+5 = (x-3)+8$ and split the integral that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=x-3$:
$$\int \frac{u+3}{\sqrt{9-u^2}} \; du$$
$$=\int \frac{u}{\sqrt{9-u^2}} \; du + \int \frac{3}{\sqrt{9-u^2}} \; du$$
Where the second integral is similar to the one you previously calculated and the first one is another substitution with $t=u^2$.  Putting it all together with your first integral yields:
$$-\sqrt{9-(x-3)^2}+8\arcsin{\left(\frac{x-3}{3}\right)}+C$$

Comment: Thanks! I see it now